# Angular transcluding attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking to pass through most of the attributes on my directive, like so:

`<my-directive name='test' 
  type='select'
  ng-required
  ng-options="v for (k,v) in types" />`

Where name and type are specific to the directive and everything else is passed through to the directive template:

`<div class='parent'><input name="hello" ng-transclude /></div>` - the input should be given an ng-required and ng-options.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link function of the directive, you can inject to it a list of the attributes you put in the directive and apply it the the element you need inside the directive, nite that if you use directive attributes you will have to use $compile to let angular comprehend it is a directive and not just an attribute